# Deleting any characters after certain character in QGIS label expression

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, field-calculator, expression, string

I have a shapefile with attribute values like this:

```
C834
K9
L523;L553
W2,T48
```

I want to display only the characters *before* certain characters, for example `;` and `,` :

```
C834
K9
L523
W2
```

How to achieve this with an label expression in QGIS 3.0?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) like this:

```
 regexp_substr("yourtextfield",'[^;]*')
```

To match more characters than `;` you can just add it to this expression like:

```
regexp_substr("yourtextfield",'[^;,]*')
```

which will return all values before `;` or `,` characters.

[image]

Comment: Do you know why your expression `'[^;]*'` did not require a double backslash `'\\'`, i.e. `'\\[^;]*'`?

Comment: @Taras I am not an regular-expressions-expert, but as square brackets are used as metacharacters here, they dont need to be escaped. You only would need to escape them, if you would search for the bracket-character `[` or `]` itself. Also the double backslash used to escape characters seems to be something QGIS specific.

Comment: Thank you for clarity

Answer (score 4):

You can use a comibination of the expressions `strpos` and `left`. `Left` returns the characters of your text from the left up to the value defined. With `strpos` you can get the position of a certain character in a string ("finding the position of the comma in your text"). Set this `-1` and you have the position until which you want your original string to go.

Combining it both for comma and semicolon, the expression looks like this, where `"val"` is the name of your attribute field:

```
left (
    left ( 
        "val", 
        ( strpos ( "val", ',') -1 )
    ), 
    ( strpos( "val", ';') -1 )
)
```

Just for completion, you can also use arrays in QGIS expressions in combination with `array_foreach` to replace a series of delimeters, without using regular expressions. The following expression removes everything after the delimiters `. , ; - _` However, in this case using the expression used by @MrXsquared is more elegant than this more complex expression:

```
array_to_string (
    array_remove_all ( 
        ( array_foreach 
            ( array ('.',',',';','-','_'), 
            if (   
                strpos (  "text", @element) =0 
                , 'delete',
                left ( 
                    "text", 
                    ( strpos ( "text", @element) - 1)
                )
            ))
        ), 
    'x')
)
```

[image]